# Is the Antikhythera clock design available as Open Source?

Tags: instructions, design

After reading and watch the video about the [Antikhythera Clock](http://acarol.woz.org/antikythera_mechanism.html), I am curious if the design reference (or better yet the instruction manual) is available as OpenSource.

Why? Because it would be cool to have one of this sitting on top of my desk.

Comment: This may sound patronizing, but did you try to contact the designer himself? There are contact informations at the bottom of his page (while you're at it, ask him to come post his answer here :-))

Comment: `Why? Because it would be cool` good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you could not get it, then you might try Hans Andersson's clock :) 
http://tiltedtwister.com/timetwister.html

And here's the instructions manual:
http://tiltedtwister.com/tmtwdownload.html